# Showing the derivative of a piecewise function is not continuous at a point

Tags: calculus

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 2x+(x^2)\sin(\frac 1x), & \text{if $x\ne 0$} \\
0, & \text{if $x=0$}\end{cases}$$

I need proof of $f'$ is not continuous at $x=0$.  And I need to describe it and say the requisite to be continuous.

Comment: Have you tried something? Did you take limits?

Comment: First you need to find out what $f'(x)$ is. When $x\neq 0$, you can do this just by differentiating. When $x=0$, you need to compute $f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}$. Now you have $f'(x)$. What does it mean to be continuous at $0$? Show that $f'(x)$ does not satisfy that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

For $x\neq 0$, $f'(x)=2(1+x\sin(\frac{1}{x}))-\cos(\frac{1}{x})$

and

$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}=0$.

but

$\lim_{x\to 0}f'(x)$ doesn't exist since

$\lim_{n \to +\infty}f'(\frac{1}{2n\pi})=1$

and

$\lim_{n \to +\infty}f'(\frac{1}{2n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}})=2$.